# MEAN Stack Application's console.log not working?

Tags: node.js, mean

I am currently developing a MEAN Stack application.

Previously my node version is 0.12 and I was using grunt to run my application which uses nodemon (which uses server.js) to run the server and watch to monitor for changes.

it works fine all the way till i upgrade my node to v 0.4.

now when I use grunt, the console.log does not print to console at all and it only works if i use

```
node server.js
```

instead of

```
grunt
```

the image below shows the situation that i'm facing:

[image]

in an ideal situation, when running grunt, I should be able to see the message

```
App listening on port 8000
```

however after updating node, the console.log doesn't seem to be working for my grunt(?)/nodemon(?) anymore.

can anyone advise on this matter?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use very useful logging module [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston). Using this you can log all your errors in a text file with timestamp, Which will be very helpful for application support. You can use it's debug, error, info methods for the corresponding console.debug(), console.error(), console.info(). 
EX:

```
Var logger = require('winston')
logger.debug('Debug things here');
logger.info('put info to track');
logger.error('to track error with status code')
```